# Where are the original research papers on when phonemes are acquired developmentally?

Tags: phonemes, language-acquisition

I received [this](https://childdevelopment.com.au/resources/child-development-charts/speech-sounds-developmental-chart/) as a guide to when the phonemes are acquired developmentally, such as:

> 1-2 years - The child is able to say the following sounds in words - /p/, /b/, /m/, /n/, /t/, /d/

Where can I find a better source based on research in the literature, specifically exactly like this, where they map the phonemes/consonants/vowels to an age when a child acquires them? Is there a standard source?